# Yii2 dependent dropdown third level onchange

Tags: javascript, yii2, dropdown

I have a 3-level dependent dropdown in yii2.
If I select the first, the second is selected automatically (if there is only one matching record of course). But the problem is the third dropdown, because it's not doing anything. The second dropdown onchange event seems to be not working in this case, however its value is changed. (It works of course if I manually change the second dropdown, but that's not what I'm expecting) Is there a workaround for this? Many thanks!

Comment: always add codes with your question. so that users can get an idea on what you have done so far.

Comment: Sorry, but I think in this case it's absolutely not necessary.

Comment: nobody has an idea?

Comment: has nobody programmed a 3-level dependent dropdown yet...? :)

Comment: well as asked earlier also, if you want someone to reply always add codes.You might think it is irrelevant but there might be users who are unable to get your question or need to see what you are doing so far.

Answer (score 0):

add this code in onchange()

```
 $.get( "'.Url::toRoute('/city/lists').'", { id: $(this).val() } )
                .done(function( data ) {
                    $( "select#selectid" ).html( data );
                }
            );' 




            <select id="selectid"></select>
```

and you have to return option value from

```
              actionList($id){
                   $list=Model::findBySql('your quer where id=$id')->all()
 foreach($list as $l){ echo "<option  value='" $l->id."'>'.$l->name.'</option>';
           }
```

I recommend you to watch this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpj7dF2orbI

Comment: It's clear how it should be done, and it works normally (manually). The problem is by the second (actually third) dropdown. When the the first dropdown is selected manually, the second is selected automatically, so its value is **changed**. But this change is not recognised by js as an `onchange` event. So the third dropdown is not showing relevant matches. I want that when I select the first dropdown, and it has one match in the second, it should be selected (it works), **and** of course, that the third is also showing relevant matches automatically. I would expect this behavior.

Comment: So the main problem is that **js** doesn't recognise the **change** of a value as an **onchange** event, or the change of the value doesn't trigger the onchange event handler or something like that (as I see).